# Why does RegCloseKey exist (when CloseHandle seems to perform the same function)?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I was looking at the docs for [`DuplicateHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251.aspx) the other day and noticed that DuplicateHandle is able to copy registry key handles (`HKEY`s). Reading up on this a bit more in the SysInternals book seems to indicate that registry key handles are plain kernel objects, similar to file handles. Yet [`CloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211.aspx) can't close `HKEY`s, and [`RegCloseKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724837.aspx) can't close other kinds of kernel objects.

Why the distinction?

Comment: Hmm, I can only guess that HKEYs were introduced earlier (in Windows 3.1), and then Microsoft didn't want to unify the interfaces even though the implementations have been merged.

Comment: I'm just guessing here:

At the end of the documentation for `CloseHandle()` it says: 

> Closing a thread handle does not terminate the associated thread or remove the thread object. Closing a process handle does not terminate the associated process or remove the process object. To remove a thread object, you must terminate the thread, then close all handles to the thread. For more information, see Terminating a Thread. To remove a process object, you must terminate the process, then close all handles to the process.

There could be similar operations done while closing a registry key.

Comment: @Philipp: That's what I thought too, except e.g. CreateFile were around in the Win3.1 days (if I'm not mistaken), and there's no "CloseFile" function.

Comment: All this came with NT, 3.1 yes, but Windows NT 3.1 there was nothing like that in Windows 3.1, no registry, no CreateFile().

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is because only a part of the functionality of the registry is implemented in the kernel. It includes the basic operations (create, delete, read, write, etc.) for working with the local registry keys.

The remaining functions are implemented in the advapi32.dll and work in the user mode:

- Access to a remote registry using `RegConnectRegistry`
- Access to the `HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA`
- Converting Win32 registry representation to Native representation
- WOW64's registry redirection on 64-bit systems (for 32-bit applications)

The kernel part of the functionality is available through the Native API: `NtCreateKey`, `NtOpenKey`, etc. When comparing these functions with the Win32 API it can be seen that the Native API uses the "classical" HANDLE  descriptors instead of HKEY.

Comment: As I already said the reason for this is that some of the functionality of the registry is implemented in the user mode (advapi32.dll), and not all HKEY objects are in fact the "real" kernel HANDLEs.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I had already deleted my comment because I saw that in the meantime :)

Comment: @Flot2011: Just curious, can you please quote the source of the information? I'm finding hard to get these kind of "insider" type information.

Comment: @yasouser: I have had a weird registry related bug once, and was forced to do a lot of digging on forums, including sysinternals forums (very useful) and a lot of low level debugging.

Comment: "•Registry redirection on 64-bit systems to 64-bit applications" should say 32-bit applications, right?